# Jacoco Reports not getting pushed to SonarCloud

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarcloud

I am using Sonarcloud with gradle plugin .
I was able to run Sonarqube analysis using gradle and push the result to Sonarcloud but for some reason the sonar plugin is not pushing the jacoco code coverage report to Sonar cloud .

I cloud see the code coverage report generated in the folder specified but sonarqube plugin refuses to push to sonar cloud

This is my sonarqube property in my build.gradle

```
sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.host.url", "https://sonarcloud.io"
            property "sonar.projectKey","xyz"
            property "sonar.projectName", "xyz"
            property "sonar.java.source", "1.8"
            property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/libs/xyz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
            property "sonar.organization", "xyz-projects"
            property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
            property "sonar.tests", "src/test"
            property "sonar.java.test.binaries", "build/classes/java/test"
            property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "build/reports/jacoco/codeCoverageReport/codeCoverageReport.xml"
            property "sonar.login", "xxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzz"

        }
}
```

Let me know if I am missing any property or any further config is needed .

Answer (score 1):

To debug cases like this, it would be good to include the exact `./gradlew sonarqube ...` command you executed, and its output when using the `--info` flag.

For now, I can say that you should not have to specify the jacoco report path explicitly, the sonarqube gradle plugin should be able to find it. Make sure the jacoco plugin is activated, for example by having a line like this:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
```

As far as I know the following properties are unnecessary to specify, the plugin detects them automatically:

> ```
> property "sonar.java.source", "1.8"
> property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/libs/xyz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
> property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
> property "sonar.tests", "src/test"
> property "sonar.java.test.binaries", "build/classes/java/test"
> ```

Lastly, as the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/) explains, the best place to configure `sonar.login` is not in `build.gradle`, but in a `gradle.properties` file, as `systemProp.sonar.login=<token>`.